# Using projection and custom SQL in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, projection

my problem is that I want to select a specific set from my database with Spring Boot, Crudrepository and a Dto object.

Therefore, I read through a lot of articles and how to do that and I think it could have something to do with Postgres?

This is the error message:

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "("
Position: 29

This is my approach:

Dto object

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class IncomeOutgoTotal {
    String person;
    float gesamt;
    String location;
}
```

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface IncomeOutgoTotalRepository extends CrudRepository<IncomeOutgo, Long> {
    @Query(value = "select new IncomeOutgoTotal (PERSON, SUM(INCOME)-SUM(OUTGO), LOCATION) from incomeoutgo where location = 'Food' group by person, location", nativeQuery = true)
    List<IncomeOutgoTotal> getTotal();
}
```

In my repository I tried the fields with lower case letters, too, but nothing helped so far.

Maybe someone can help me here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot construct an object in a SQL query, that will only work in a JPQL query.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix my problem now, and it worked with the CrudRepository.
Others on the Internet did it the same way, either using CrudRepository or JPARepository.

This is my solution

```
public interface IncomeOutgoTotalRepository extends CrudRepository<IncomeOutgo, Long> {
    @Query(value = "select new at.co.netconsulting.incomesandexpenses.domain.IncomeOutgoTotal (person, SUM(income)-SUM(outgo) as total, location) from IncomeOutgo where location = 'Food' group by person, location")
    List<IncomeOutgoTotal> getTotal();
}

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class IncomeOutgoTotal {
    String person;
    double total;
    String location;
}
```

Dto class members as well as @Query fields must be written the same way, and the package must also be written in the Repository.

Then it worked.